# Python property setter infinite loop with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that will take in text and info from a GUI window, and send an automated written email out. It's for an on-campus job (Lab Attendant) I have where I was tired of writing the same email over and over for students who leave stuff in the computer labs. Pretty much first time I am writing in Python (coming from Java and C).

I intend to take the info in, make objects Lab Attendant and Student for all the info containing the email, password, name, etc. Then it creates a string from the info in the objects, and sends an email using smtplib.

The problem I am coming into, is that when it is setting properties in the objects, starting with the very first lab attendant property email, it just gets stuck looping over and over in the set function.

[image]

I'm not sure why, I've tried giving it a return to break out but it doesn't even get to that line. It just stays stuck on line 52

> ```
>    self.email = email
> ```

Here is the full code.

```
from tkinter import *  # GUI library
import tkinter.messagebox
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# @author: xxxx
# Sends automated emails out for lab attendant job

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, email, item):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.item = item

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        self.email = email

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def item(self):
        return self.item

    @item.setter
    def item(self, item):
        self.item = item

class LabAttendant:
    def __init__(self, email, password, lab):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.lab = lab

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        self.email = email

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password = password

    @property
    def lab(self):
        return self.lab

    @lab.setter
    def lab(self, password):
        self.password = password

def SendEmail(labattendant, student):
    # message = MIMEMultipart()
    # message['From'] = labattendant.email
    # message['To'] = student.email
    # message['Subject'] = student.item + " left in " + labattendant.lab
    if "id" == student.item:
        body = "Hello " + student.name + ",\n I believe you left your " + student.item + " in the " + labattendant.lab \
               + " computer lab. If so, please stop by the " + labattendant.lab + " computer lab "
    else:
        body = "Hello " + student.name + ",\n I believe you left your " + student.item + " in the " + labattendant.lab\
               + " computer lab. If so, please stop by the " + labattendant.lab\
               + " computer lab with your ID and ask the lab " + "attendant to return your" + student.item + "to you.\n"


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        student_info_frame = Frame(frame)
        student_info_frame.pack(side=TOP)
        labattendant_info_frame = Frame(frame)
        labattendant_info_frame.pack(side=TOP)

        # Student name, email, item
        student_name_label = Label(student_info_frame, text="Student name: ")
        student_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        student_name_entry = Entry(student_info_frame)
        student_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        student_email_label = Label(student_info_frame, text="Student email: ")
        student_email_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        student_email_entry = Entry(student_info_frame)
        student_email_entry.insert(END, '@school.edu')
        student_email_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        student_item_label = Label(student_info_frame, text="Item left behind: ")
        student_item_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        student_item_entry = Entry(student_info_frame)
        student_item_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

        # Lab attendant email, password, lab working in
        labattendant_email_label = Label(labattendant_info_frame, text="Your email: ")
        labattendant_email_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
        labattendant_email_entry = Entry(labattendant_info_frame)
        labattendant_email_entry.insert(END, '@school.edu')
        labattendant_email_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        labattendant_password_label = Label(labattendant_info_frame, text="Email password: ")
        labattendant_password_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
        labattendant_password_entry = Entry(labattendant_info_frame, show='*')
        labattendant_password_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)
        labattendant_lab_label = Label(labattendant_info_frame, text="Current lab: ")
        labattendant_lab_label.grid(row=5, column=0)
        lab_defualt = StringVar(labattendant_info_frame)
        labattendant_lab_menu = OptionMenu(labattendant_info_frame, lab_defualt, "MCT054", "CUB124", "GRH106")
        labattendant_lab_menu.grid(row=5, column=1)

        # Button handler for the submit button
        def submit_on_click():
            if "@school.edu" not in labattendant_email_entry.get():
                tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please use your @school.edu email.")
                labattendant_email_entry.delete(0, 'end')
            else:
                labattendant = LabAttendant(labattendant_email_entry.get(), labattendant_password_entry.get(),
                                            labattendant_lab_menu.cget("text"))
                student = Student(student_name_entry.get(), student_email_entry.get(), student_item_entry.get().lower())
                SendEmail(labattendant, student)


        # Collects data and sends it
        submit_button = Button(frame, text="Send Email", command=submit_on_click)
        submit_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root = Tk()
GUI = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, you don't need getters and setters for ordinary attribute access. Use a `@property` only if you need to run special code whenever the user accesses and/or modifies an attribute. And when you do that, you must take care with naming to avoid the problem you encountered.

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name, email, item):

        # For example, there might be no need for name and item properties.
        self.name = name
        self.item = item

        # But maybe we want to validate email addresses.
        # Note that we will store the email address in self._email.
        self._email = None
        self.email = email

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        if email_is_valid(email):
            self._email = email
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid email')

def email_is_valid(email):
    return '@' in email

print Student('x', 'a@foo.com', 1).email
print Student('y', 'bar', 2).email
```

Answer (score 4):

A property name can't be the same as an attribute name (in the same class).